# Reflection, has IsClass but no IsStruct?

Tags: .net, reflection

How do i check if a Type is a struct? IsClass worked perfectly then my reflection stop behaving as i expected when i change the class to the struct. How do i check if its a struct? -edit- i need to check for class/structs. Nothing else, i cant match longs, ints, etc by accident. DateTime may be ok i am using this to search a Attribute/FieldType inside of the type i am checking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Type.IsValueType` should do the trick.

Comment: Now long and ints are confused with structs.

Comment: @acidzombie24: `long` and `int` **are** structs. What confusion? Maybe you mean `IsPrimitive`?

Comment: I can write IsPrimitive == false (as a shortcut and i have an alternative to most primitives) and use IsValueType. Thanks :)

Comment: acidzombie24: note this will depend on what you want to exclude.  For example, `decimal` is **NOT** a primitive, even though it looks that way in C#.  Hopefully this won't be an issue for your use case...

Comment: itowlson: Test are all in place and decimal isnt an issue. There are select types i support and user structs are one but only if it has certain attributes :)