# How to determine if Type is a struct?

Tags: c#, .net, types, struct

Given a `PropertyInfo` instance, which has a `Type` property, how does one determine if it is a struct? I found there are properties such as `IsPrimitive`, `IsInterface`, etc. but I'm not sure how to ask for a struct?

**EDIT:**
To clarify question.
Suppose I have a method:

```
public Boolean Check(PropertyInfo pi)
{
   return pi.Type.IsStruct;
}
```

What do I write instead of `IsStruct`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Type.IsValueType should do the trick.

(pinched from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083012/reflection-has-isclass-but-no-isstruct))

Comment: Thanks. 
I guess I'll also have to check for !IsPrimitive, but that should do the trick.

Comment: @Dejan: also the primitives (such as boolean) are structs.

Comment: You're right, you'll need the !IsPrimitive. What about an Extension method? :D

Comment: @Fredrik: Thanks, I know - but I need to check only for 'custom' structs, so I ended up with something like: return type.IsValueType && !type.IsPrimitive && type != typeof(Decimal); which works for this particular need.

Comment: To work around things like typeof(Decimal), I decided for one project that I would exclude all types starting with "System." - this was the right thing to do in my project. Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Structs and enums (`IsEnum`) fall under the superset called value types (`IsValueType`). Primitive types (`IsPrimitive`) are a subset of struct. Which means all primitive types are structs but not vice versa; for eg, `int` is a primitive type as well as struct, but `decimal` is only a struct, not a primitive type.

So you see the only missing property there is that of a struct. Easy to write one:

```
public bool IsStruct(this Type type)
{
   return type.IsValueType && !type.IsEnum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

putting the comments on Antony Koch 's answer into an extention method:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions {
        public static bool IsCustomValueType(this Type type) {            
               return type.IsValueType && !type.IsPrimitive && type.Namespace != null && !type.Namespace.StartsWith("System.");
        }
    }
```

should work

Comment: Consider whether you want to include or exclude `IsEnum` — if you're only looking for custom structs.